# Converting a date into a key failing

Tags: oracle

I have scoured the sources and every version of this I've tried fails.
Basically, this function takes a date and should returns number.

For example: 4/1/2010, would return as -20160401
It seemed simple enough, but this is costing me hours of time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MAKE_KEY( DT DATE ) RETURN NUMBER IS

DATE_KEY NUMBER := 0;
yyyy SMALLINT := 2000;
mm SMALLINT := 1;
dd SMALLINT := 1;

BEGIN
        IF DT IS NOT NULL THEN
            yyyy := YEAR(DT);
            mm := MONTH(DT);
            dd := DAY(DT);
        END IF; 
        DATE_KEY := (-1 * (yyyy * 10000 + mm * 100 + dd));

        RETURN  DATE_KEY;

END MAKE_KEY;
```

Comment: You've tagged as oracle but code is not oracle. Please set proper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and shortest solution is this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MAKE_KEY( DT DATE ) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   RETURN TO_CHAR(DT, '-YYYYMMDD');
END;
```

You don't even need a function for that, you can use `TO_CHAR(DT, '-YYYYMMDD')` directly in SQL or PL/SQL.

It would return different result for dates `BC` but I don't thing this is relevant in your case, otherwise do `RETURN -1*TO_CHAR(DT, 'YYYYMMDD');`

In case you need `0` for `NULL` input, you can do `COALESCE(TO_CHAR(NULL, '-YYYYMMDD'),0)`

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, and it wouldn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should write this in plsql :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MAKE_KEY( DT DATE ) RETURN NUMBER IS

DATE_KEY NUMBER := 0;
yyyy SMALLINT := 2000;
mm SMALLINT := 1;
dd SMALLINT := 1;

BEGIN
        IF DT IS NOT NULL THEN
            yyyy := extract(year from DT);
            mm := extract(month from DT);
            dd := extract(day from DT);
        END IF; 
        DATE_KEY := (-1 * (yyyy * 10000 + mm * 100 + dd));

        RETURN  DATE_KEY;

END MAKE_KEY;
```